# SVN - how to get a list of commit messages with respective revisions (command-line)

Tags: svn, command-line, commit, message

I'm looking for something like this below:

r999999 - Commit Message

Comment: You mean like `svn log`?

Comment: You should show your work

Comment: I'm sorry, but it is unclear what you are asking about and what your plan is. Please, elaborate.

Comment: just want to get a log on the format above.

Comment: revisions and messages , in same line

Answer (score 0):

If you want to process the log programmatically, then you can try

```
svn log --xml
```

This will give you the log in a machine-readable format that you can process or re-format in any way you want.